# beautifulSoup does not match chrome inspect while Python webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to webscrape protein sequences off of the ncbi protein database. At this point, the user can search for a protein and I can get the link to the first result that the database spits out. However, when I run this through beautiful soup, the soup does not match the chrome inspect element, nor does it have the sequence at all.

Here is my current code:

```
import string
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getSequence():
    searchProt = input("Enter a Protein Name!:")
    if searchProt != '':
        searchString = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=" + searchProt
        page = requests.get(searchString)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        soup = str(soup)
        accIndex = soup.find("a")
        accessionStart = soup.find('<dd>',accIndex)
        accessionEnd = soup.find('</dd>', accessionStart + 4)
        accession = soup[accessionStart + 4: accessionEnd]
        newSearchString = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/" + accession
        try:
            newPage = requests.get(newSearchString)
            #This is where it fails
            newSoup = BeautifulSoup(newPage.text, 'html.parser')
            aaList = []
            spaceCount = newSoup.count("ff_line")
            print(spaceCount)
            for i in range(spaceCount):
                startIndex = newSoup.find("ff_line")
                startIndex = newSoup.find(">", startIndex) + 2
                nextAA = newSoup[startIndex]
                while nextAA in string.ascii_lowercase:
                    aaList.append(nextAA)
                    startIndex += 1
                    nextAA = newSoup[startIndex]
            return aaList        
         except:
            print("Please Enter a Valid Protein")
```

I have been trying to run it with the search 'p53' and have gotten to the link: [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/AAC53040.1)

I have looked at a long series of webscraping entries on this website and tried a lot of things including installing selenium and using different parsers. I am still confused about why these don't match. (Sorry if this is a repeat question, I am very new to webscraping and currently have a concussion so I am looking for a bit of individual case feedback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will extract the protein sequence you want using Selenium. I've modified your original code to give you the result you wanted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def getSequence():
    searchProt = input("Enter a Protein Name!:")
    if searchProt != '':
        searchString = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=" + searchProt
        page = requests.get(searchString)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        soup = str(soup)
        accIndex = soup.find("a")
        accessionStart = soup.find('<dd>',accIndex)
        accessionEnd = soup.find('</dd>', accessionStart + 4)
        accession = soup[accessionStart + 4: accessionEnd]
        newSearchString = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/" + accession
        try:
            driver.get(newSearchString)
            html = driver.page_source
            newSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
            ff_tags = newSoup.find_all(class_="ff_line")
            aaList = []
            for tag in ff_tags:
                aaList.append(tag.text.strip().replace(" ",""))
            protSeq = "".join(aaList)
            return protSeq
        except:
            print("Please Enter a Valid Protein")

sequence = getSequence()
print(sequence)
```

Which produces the following output for input of "p53":

```
meepqsdlsielplsqetfsdlwkllppnnvlstlpssdsieelflsenvtgwledsggalqgvaaaaastaedpvtetpapvasapatpwplsssvpsyktfqgdygfrlgflhsgtaksvtctyspslnklfcqlaktcpvqlwvnstpppgtrvramaiykklqymtevvrrcphherssegdslappqhlirvegnlhaeylddkqtfrhsvvvpyeppevgsdcttihynymcnsscmggmnrrpiltiitledpsgnllgrnsfevricacpgrdrrteeknfqkkgepcpelppksakralptntssspppkkktldgeyftlkirgherfkmfqelnealelkdaqaskgsedngahssylkskkgqsasrlkklmikregpdsd
```